# Using SQL Server to mimic EXCEL INT to DATE logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have a table with the following "Updated Date" field. I need to convert this to YYYY/MM/DD similar to how the excel logic is doing it. The image shows the correct date and the formula that converts it. How would I convert these numbers to the same date shown in the image using SQL? (N14 = 113158)

[image]

Comment: The image doesn't load for me. Can you check the URL?

Comment: @J.MSmith try this: http://imgur.com/a/Tx6s5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @i int = 113158
Select dateadd(year, @i/1000, @i%1000-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the first day of that year, then adding the days to it.

That way it'll also give the correct result when it's a leap year.

```sql
select 
EAUPMU,  

DATEADD(day, (EAUPMU % 1000)-1, DATEFROMPARTS((1900 + EAUPMU/1000),1,1)) as [EauPmuDate],  

DATEADD(day, (EAUPMU % 1000)-1, dateadd(year,EAUPMU/1000,0)) as [EauPmuDateTime]  

from (
  values (113158),(112158)
) as T(EAUPMU);
```

Result :

```
EAUPMU  EauPmuDate  EauPmuDateTime
113158  2013-06-07  2013-06-07 00:00:00.000
112158  2012-06-06  2012-06-06 00:00:00.000
```